# Подскажите, как реализовать правильно перевод вывода даты через класс Carbon?

Tags: база-данных, laravel, дата, carbon

Пытаюсь перевести и вывести дату через класс Карбон - но выводится всё на английском? Как исправить?

в AppServiceProvider я написал -

```
public function boot()
{

    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU');
    Carbon::setLocale(config('app.locale'));
}
```

соответственно в app

```
'locale' => 'ru',
```

Во Вьюхе -

```
{{$review->created_at->format('F, d, Y')}}
```

Comment: Вернее как вывести на русском языке - ДЕК, ОКТ, МАРТ, ( Сокращенный месяц) - остальное уже вроде как нашёл)

Answer (score 0):

Я вот таким способом приводил дату к русскому варианту (именно через `isoformat`):

```
{{\Carbon\Carbon::parse($review->created_at)->isoformat("D MMMM Y в H:m")}}
```

Насколько помню, для этого способа должна стоять русская локаль в операционной системе сервера.

Comment: Спасибо, но вроде как решил - всё работает, с помощью такого кода - {{$review->created_at->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y')}}